# Why is there a Users directory in my Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I set up an Eclipse project with Maven. The sources are versioned using Git. The work environment is Windows.

For some reason a "Users" directory is visible in the project tree, containing the following structure:

```
Users
+--kaupps
  +--git
    +--<projectname>
      +--<projectname>
        +--target
          +--m2e-wtp
             +--web-resources
               +--META-INF
                 +--maven
                   +--<EclipseProjectName>
                   | +--<EclipseProjectName>
                   |   +--pom.properties
                   |   +--pom.xml
                   +--MANIFEST.mf
```

What's the purpose of this directory and do I need to check it in to Version Control or is ignoring it better? pom.xml at the project's top is checked in already.

Comment: This directory must belong to Maven/Eclipse. Git keeps all of it's information inside a `.git` directory in the root folder of your project.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're doing there, but it seems like the tree you generated there contains more than what's under your version control root....

Comment: i have faced a similar problem when using Eclipse in Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude the `target`-Directory from source control. Usually generated resources from maven are put into that directory.

This is basically equivalent to excluding `bin/` from source control since both directories contain build-process artifacts that can (and often will) change on every build. Versioning them is not useful.

Comment: The target directory is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

`c:/Users/<username>/git/` is the default directory of git. This is where the project is located on your disc. You should just check-in the `<projectname>` directory.

Comment: I understand that this is where the local Repository stores it's content. But why does this show up within Eclipse and what should I do with it?

Comment: In which view do you see this directory tree? In the `Project Explorer` or `Package Explorer` you shouldn't.

Comment: I see it in the Project Explorer. And yes, I feel like I shouldn't. :-)